# From what Apache Flink checkpoints consist of?

Tags: apache-flink

I already know that I can use checkpoints in Apache Flink for fault tolerance. The question in that what Flink really saves when he makes checkpoint?

[Here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.5/ops/state/checkpoints.html) I found an explanation "similarly to savepoints, a checkpoint consists of a meta data file and, depending on the state backend, some additional data files".

From what metadata file and the additional files consist of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://flink.apache.org/features/2018/01/30/incremental-checkpointing.html) blogpost has a good description of how Flink’s incremental checkpointing works with an example of Local RocksDB directories. See 'How it works' section.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Nizar. Actually, I wanted some more low level explanation, but it'll good place to start research.